# how to prevent other views refreshing in state change swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have a bottom navigation view in my main View that I want to hide in some of the inner views by a `@published` variable that defined in ViewModel, but when I change the value of the variable all of the body refreshes in the main view and cause some problems(losing data). I want just to refresh the state of the bottom navigation, not the entire body. here is my code:

**MainView**

```
struct MainView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack{
            content
        }
        
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                BottomNavigationView(mainViewModel: self.viewModel)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
            }.opacity(viewModel.isBottomNavigationVisible ? 1 : 0)


    }
}

var content: some View {
    switch self.viewModel.currentView {
    case .plan:
        return PlanMainView(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
    case .me:
        return MeMainView(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
    case .onBoarding:
        return OnBoardingHome(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
}}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published private(set) var currentView: Modules = .main
@Published var isBottomNavigationVisible: Bool = true


func hideBottomBar() {
    self.isBottomNavigationVisible = false
}

func showBottomBar() {
    self.isBottomNavigationVisible = true
}

func GoToView(view: Modules) {
    self.currentView = view
}}
```

**MeMainView**

this is the view that I want to hide the bottom navigation in onAppear

```
struct MeMainView: View {
@ObservedObject var mainViewModel:MainViewModel


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
       Text("MewView")
    }.onAppear{
        self.mainViewModel.hideBottomBar()
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of computable property move `content` into separated view, as nothing changed for it so it will not be refreshed

```
    VStack{
        BodyView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
```

and

```
struct BodyView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel

   var body: some View {
      switch self.viewModel.currentView {
      case .plan:
        return PlanMainView(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
      case .me:
        return MeMainView(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
      case .onBoarding:
        return OnBoardingHome(mainViewModel: viewModel).eraseToAnyView()
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but still, refreshes the view


struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MainContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    BottomNavigationView(mainViewModel: self.viewModel)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                }.opacity(viewModel.isBottomNavigationVisible ? 1 : 0)
    }
    }
}

Comment: The body of MainView will alway be refreshed because it depends on modified `viewModel.isBottomNavigationVisible`. The idea is to separate other parts into subview which body will not be refreshed.